# I wanted to add a outline property on hovered element only not on parent elements

Tags: html, css

I wanted to add property further on clock so added a outline type effect property .
But whenever I hover on element parent element hover property is also activated . Know this is type bubbling/capturing effect in JS and also this is how CSS works.

Plz CSS only if possible : may be JS can be used like this

```
onhover="func()"

getElementId().style.boxShadow = " "
```

have to add to every element

Can it be possible have outline property on hovered element only .

> Any suggestion on better property for `outline-radius` or `outline effect with radius` are very needed

Thanks for help

```css
#clockOuterCircle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 42vw;
  height: 42vw;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid rgb(255, 62, 62);
  background-color: rgb(253, 133, 133);
  user-select: none;
}

#clockOuterCircle:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(119, 239, 255, 0.5);
}

#clockInnerCircle {
  position: relative;
  width: 38vw;
  height: 38vw;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 6px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

#clockInnerCircle:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(119, 239, 255, 0.5);
}

#clockStyleCircle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16vw;
  height: 16vw;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0%;
  top: 28.5%;
  left: 28.5%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(255, 233, 35);
}

#clockStyleCircle:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(119, 239, 255, 0.5);
}

#clockStyleEyeCircle1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 4vw;
  height: 4vw;
  top: 24%;
  left: 10%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1.5vw 1px 0.1vh rgb(255, 86, 86);
  /* inset 16px 0px #777, inset 16px 0px 1px 2px #777;*/
  background-color: black;
}

#clockStyleEyeCircle2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 4vw;
  height: 4vw;
  top: 24%;
  left: 65%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1.5vw 1px 0.1vh rgb(255, 86, 86);
  background-color: black;
}

#clockStyleSimileCircle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 8vw;
  height: 3vw;
  top: 68%;
  left: 25%;
  border: 3px solid rgb(36, 36, 36);
  /* border-radius: 0 0 50% 50% /  0 0 100% 100%; */
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100% 200%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100% 200%;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1.5vw 1px 0.1vh rgb(255, 86, 86);
}

#clockCenterDot {
  position: absolute;
  width: 4%;
  height: 4%;
  top: 48%;
  left: 48%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px;
  z-index: 4;
}

#hourNeedle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30%;
  width: 2%;
  top: 20%;
  left: 49%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#minuteNeedle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 38%;
  width: 1.6%;
  top: 12%;
  left: 49.2%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#secondNeedle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 46%;
  width: 1%;
  top: 8%;
  left: 49.5%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="clockOuterCircle">
  <div id="clockInnerCircle">
    <div id="clockStyleCircle">
    </div>
    <div id="clockCenterDot"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not). It might help

Comment: Yes it is the first way I thought but then changed because have to add `:not()` in all element . As going to add on hour min sec hand .

Comment: `:not()` `JS` are my last weapons if possible else I will go with your way @HarshitRastogi

Comment: Maybe this approach of child-sibling can help you http://jsfiddle.net/k3Zdt/11/

Comment: Please explain _clearly_ what about how your snippet currently renders is supposed to be different, because currently I can't tell what exactly you want here.

Comment: But when apply hover property on parent then no matter on which element you hover parent:hover property is applied @HarshitRastogi . I tried adding background-color property on hover on parent element

Comment: Here in snippet when I hover on inner element the hover property is applied to parent elements also . I want to limit this to hovered element only @CBroe

Comment: Still not sure what exactly that is supposed to mean here, how it is supposed to actually look. But either way - there is nothing you can do about how hover "bubbles up" through the DOM. If you don't want to go for a JS-based solution instead - then you will need to find a way to build the same layout with elements that are _not_ nested into each other.

Comment: Ok  @CBroe but can you tell something about adding a outline radius like effect which is used in above code something different and accurate

Comment: Not without knowing in what you you would want it to be "different", or where you are missing "accuracy" here in the first place.

Comment: with accuracy I mean fix width as you can see in snippet outline is somewhat thin at bottom so any different approach in code if possible @CBroe

Comment: To avoid the bubbling hover, you can try layering the divs instead of setting a child hierarchy.
Set a parent div with display flex and position relative and then set all "hoverable" divs next to each other. I could mean a little more work but then you avoid the hover issue.